# Intelligent excel filtering and copying

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a solution for the following problem. Sports analytics stuff.

Sheet 1: ~3000 rows, 4 columns, namely down, distance, position, Expected Points (EP). 
Sheet 2: ~1500 rows, 4 columns, namely down, distance, position, and an EMPTY EP column.

What I want from a function or filter: checks Sheet 2 values for the first 3 columns, searches for the exact match in Sheet 1, and then takes the EP value from Sheet 1 for the corresponding row, and copies it to Sheet 2 empty EP cell for the row with equivalent values.

Example: 2, 15, 39 in Sheet 2. Checks the exact row on Sheet 1, where values are 2, 15, 39, some EP. Then takes the EP, and copies it to Sheet 2 EP column in the row I'm working with.

Does someone have any advice? Thinking about advanced filters, vlookup with nested ifs and ands, but no solution for the exact problem popped into my mind.

Comment: can be easier with Power Query merge or Microsoft Query join https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9cUYpXIKsU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution

1. Insert a column on the left of all the data on Sheet2
2. enter the formula =concatenate(B2,C2,D2) in row 2 if you have headings
3. Auto fill down to the end of your data
4. On sheet1 Empty EP column enter on row 2 `=iferror(vlookup(A2&B2&C2,Sheet2!A:E,false,5),"")`
5. auto fill down to the end of your data.

You should now have the matching data in the column.

It is possible to do the lookup without creating the extra column but it's much easier if you do create that lookup column.